# Get Monitor dpi scale

Tags: wpf, dpi

I have a WPF application created in .NET 6 running on Windows 10

Given a system with two monitors, where one monitor is set to 100% scaling and the other is set to 200% scaling. How can I get the DPI scaling of the monitor the application window is currently on?

I've tried using `VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi()` where I pass in the window. But it always returns the scaling of the primary monitor (the one checked in 'Make this my main display' in the Windows 10 Display settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `app.manifest` file to your application and turn on per monitor DPI awareness as [examplified on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/main/PerMonitorDPI):

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<windowsSettings>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
</windowsSettings>
</application>
```

Then you should be able to get the DPI of the current monitor using the `VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi` API:

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).PixelsPerDip
```